# FTX get account info using Python gives Not logged in error

Tags: python, python-requests, cryptocurrency

I tried to connect to FTX using Python to get account information but it keeps giving me not logged in error; my code shown below:

```
from requests import Request, Session
import time
import hmac

method = 'GET'
ENDPOINT = 'https://ftx.com/api/'
# ENDPOINT = 'https://ftx.us/api/'
path = 'account'

API_KEY = '...'
API_SECRET = '...'

request = Request(method, ENDPOINT + path)

ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
prepared = request.prepare()
print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(ts, prepared.method, prepared.path_url))
signature_payload = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(ts, prepared.method, prepared.path_url).encode()
if prepared.body:
    signature_payload += prepared.body
signature = hmac.new(API_SECRET.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()

request.headers['FTX-KEY'] = API_KEY
request.headers['FTX-SIGN'] = signature
request.headers['FTX-TS'] = str(ts)

# get data...
request1 = request.prepare()
print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(ts, request1.method, request1.path_url))
response = Session().send(request1)
data = response.json()
```

the data gives me:

```
{'success': False, 'error': 'Not logged in'}
```

I wonder where I did wrong? I locate in US is this might cause issue? and my account hasn't traded anything yet not sure if that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, it's been a while and I haven't done much more work on this.. but I believe it's because of the location.. if the account is registered under FTX international this should work...

Answer (score 0):

Please change headers to the following and url to ftx.us/api

```
request.headers['FTXUS-KEY'] = API_KEY
request.headers['FTXUS-SIGN'] = signature
request.headers['FTXUS-TS'] = str(ts)
```